# How to add Akka dependencies in Jupyter notebook Scala?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a requirement to add dependecies to one of my program on Akka framework using Jupyter notebook.

Hence, I tried by using using classpath.add() in the code itself. However, when I execute the code I get the following error:

not found: value classpath

Please find the error screenshot attached and help me with resolving this error

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYvVV.jpg)

Comment: Where is error screenshot?

Comment: click on the screenshot tag